# VHDL testbench code not showing output result of 1bit fulladder

Tags: vhdl, test-bench, active-hdl

here code some warning but no errors found but test bench of this fulladder output waveform sum and carry not showing. there shown u in the carry and sum output, but not inputs are fine only sum and carry output is the problem why is that, in here have some warning, sometime i have doubt about that warning , here  i attached the image you an refer it and give me some advise to solve this problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQqv6.png)

```
 -- 1-bit full adder testbench
 -- A testbench is used to rigorously tests a design that you have made.
 -- The output of the testbench should allow the designer to see if
 -- the design worked. The testbench should also report where the testbench
 -- failed.
  LIBRARY IEEE;
  use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
  -- Declare a testbench. Notice that the testbench does not have any input
 -- or output ports.
entity tb_1bitfulladder is
end tb_1bitfulladder;
 -- Describes the functionality of the tesbench.
 architecture MY_TEST of tb_1bitfulladder is
 -- The object that we wish to test is declared as a component of
 -- the test bench. Its functionality has already been described elsewhere.
 -- This simply describes what the object's inputs and outputs are, it
 -- does not actually create the object.
     component FULL_ADDER
      port( x, y, Cin : in STD_LOGIC;
       s, Cout : out STD_LOGIC );
     end component;
     -- Specifies which description of the adder you will use.
     --for U1: FULL_ADDER use entity WORK.FULL_ADDER(MY_DATAFLOW);
     -- Create a set of signals which will be associated with both the inputs
     -- and outputs of the component that we wish to test.
    signal X_s, Y_s : STD_LOGIC:='0';
    signal CIN_s : STD_LOGIC:='0';
    signal SUM_s : STD_LOGIC;
    signal COUT_s : STD_LOGIC;
    -- This is where the testbench for the FULL_ADDER actually begins.
  BEGIN
   -- Create a 1-bit full adder in the testbench.
    -- The signals specified above are mapped to their appropriate
     -- roles in the 1-bit full adder which we have created.
  UUT: FULL_ADDER port map (x=>X_s,       --(//this line has some warning i put it below END Othecode)
                         y=>Y_s,
                         Cin=>CIN_s,
                         s => SUM_s, 
                         Cout=> COUT_s
);
  -- The process is where the actual testing is done.       
  -- stimulus process
   stim_proc:process
      begin
  -- We are now going to set the inputs of the adder and test
  -- the outputs to verify the functionality of our 1-bit full adder.
  -- Case 0 : 0+0 with carry in of 0.
  -- Set the signals for the inputs.
   X_s <= '0';
   Y_s <= '0';
   CIN_s <= '0';
 -- Wait a short amount of time and then check to see if the
 -- outputs are what they should be. If not, then report an error
  -- so that we will know there is a problem.
  wait for 10 ns;

  assert ( SUM_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 0 - SUM" severity error;
  assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 0 - COUT" severity error;
  wait for 40 ns;
   -- Carry out the same process outlined above for the other 7 cases.
   -- Case 1 : 0+0 with carry in of 1.
   X_s <= '0';
   Y_s <= '0';
   CIN_s <= '1';
   wait for 10 ns;
   assert ( SUM_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 1 - SUM" severity error;
   assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 1 - COUT" severity error;
   wait for 40 ns;
-- Case 2 : 0+1 with carry in of 0.
   X_s <= '0';
   Y_s <= '1';
   CIN_s <= '0';
   wait for 10 ns;
   assert ( SUM_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 2 - SUM" severity error;
   assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 2 - COUT" severity error;
   wait for 40 ns;
  -- Case 3 : 0+1 with carry in of 1.
   X_s <= '0';
   Y_s <= '1';
  CIN_s <= '1';
  wait for 10 ns;
  assert ( SUM_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 3 - SUM" severity error;
  assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 3 - COUT" severity error;
  wait for 40 ns;
 -- Case 4 : 1+0 with carry in of 0.
  X_s <= '1';
  Y_s <= '0';
 CIN_s <= '0';
 wait for 10 ns;
 assert ( SUM_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 4 - SUM" severity error;
 assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 4 - COUT" severity error;
 wait for 40 ns;
 -- Case 5 : 1+0 with carry in of 1.
  X_s <= '1';
  Y_s <= '0';
  CIN_s <= '1';
  wait for 10 ns;
  assert ( SUM_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 5 - SUM" severity error;
  assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 5 - COUT" severity error;
  wait for 40 ns;
  -- Case 6 : 1+1 with carry in of 0.
   X_s <= '1';
   Y_s <= '1';
   CIN_s <= '0';
   wait for 10 ns;
    assert ( SUM_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 6 - SUM" severity error;
    assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 6 - COUT" severity error;
   wait for 40 ns;
  -- Case 7 : 1+1 with carry in of 1.
   X_s <= '1';
   Y_s <= '1';
   CIN_s <= '1';

   wait for 10 ns;
  assert ( SUM_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 7 - SUM" severity error;
  assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 7 - COUT" severity error;
  wait for 40 ns;
  end process;
END MY_TEST;
```

```
Warning: ELAB1_0026: tb_1bitfulladder.vhd : (35, 0): There is no default binding for component     "FULL_ADDER". (No entity named "FULL_ADDER" was found).
```

Comment: The error is because it cannot find the code for `FULL_ADDER`. You will need to add it before simulating.

Comment: its not an error, its a warning , if it would be an error then  I cannot run the simulation like above attached image.

Comment: It's not illegal to elaborate a design hierarchy with one or more component instantiations unbound, think of it as a bread board with a component not installed. It's specifically allowed by the VHDL standard. You have no explicit binding and default binding doesn't identify entity FULL_ADDER as being directly visible, it hasn't been successfully analyzed (compiled) and added to the working library and there's no library clause and use clause making it visible in another reference library. Simulator vendors add a warning for those who don't intend to leave components unbound.

Comment: This `--for U1: FULL_ADDER use entity WORK.FULL_ADDER(MY_DATAFLOW);` un-commented  and UUT substituted for U1 would be a configuration specification providing an explicit binding indication. Your course instructor intended you to sucessfully analyze entity FULL_ADDER and architecture DATAFLOW into the current working library. With an explicit binding indication you'd get an error.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.5 Order of analysis "If any error is detected while attempting to analyze a design unit, then the attempted analysis is rejected and has no effect whatsoever on the current working library."  Did you attempt to analyze  FULL_ADDER  and it's architecture into the current working library and did it fail?

Comment: okay thank you  I am finally solved it. now it shows the waveform test bench 1 bit fulladder output sum and Cout